# SQL Query where NOT IN using LIKE or REGEXP

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table.

How can I return all rows where IP_ADD does not contain 12.23.34.XX, 13.23.34.XX, 12.23.35.27, or 13.23.35.27 where XX represents any number?

For instance, using this data, only the last two rows should be returned.

```
+----+---------------+
| ID |    IP_ADD     |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | '12.23.34.45' |
|  2 | '12.23.34.46' |
|  3 | '12.23.34.47' |
|  4 | '12.23.34.48' |
|  5 | '13.23.34.45' |
|  6 | '13.23.34.46' |
|  7 | '13.23.34.47' |
|  8 | '13.23.34.48' |
|  9 | '12.23.35.27' |
| 10 | '13.23.35.27' |
| 11 | '13.33.34.45' |
| 12 | '13.33.34.45' |
+----+---------------+
```

Comment: can you paste the original query?

Comment: @jcho360 In the past, I would use `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE IP_ADD NOT IN ('12.23.34.45', '12.23.34.46', etc, etc, '13.23.35.27');`.  I wish to use ranges instead of hardcoding each IP_ADD not to include.

Comment: I think we can do better than the solutions so far provided. Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET (for the stated criteria)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
where 
not  (IP_ADD in  ('12.23.35.27', '13.23.35.27') or 
IP_ADD like ('12.23.34.%') or
IP_ADD like ('13.23.34.%'));
```

Comment: After seeing Lamak's answer, I was thinking of something like this one.

Comment: Are multiple values separated by parenthesis allowed in the `not like` clause?

Comment: if you want to add more values, you can use `not in ('val1','val2',....,'valn')` , if you are going to use only 1 IP, use Lamak query.

Comment: Yes, I will have multiple individual IPs and multiple IP ranges to exclude.  Will something similar to `IP_ADD not like ('13.23.34.%', '12.23.34.%')` work?

Comment: no, each like have to be separate from the other. I.E: `or 
IP_ADD not like ('12.23.34.%') or IP_ADD not like ('12.23.35.%') or IP_ADD not like ....;`

Comment: Ok.  Thanks.  It might be helpful to others if you update your answer to reflect this?

Comment: I'll wait a bit just to see if anything else comes in, but this appears to be the best answer, and I plan on accepting it.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Small flaw.  If it is `NOT IN` or `NOT LIKE` one of the constraints, the next constraint will return true overriding the NOT clause.

Comment: The following will work: `SELECT * FROM myTable 
WHERE NOT (
    IP_ADD IN  ('12.23.35.27', '13.23.35.27')
    OR IP_ADD LIKE ('12.23.34.%')
    OR IP_ADD LIKE ('13.23.34.%')
};`